# Determine how external memory is allocated when using a std::function object

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to determine how the external memory of a `std::function` object is allocated? `std::function` might not allocate external memory if it is feed with a raw C function pointer, but it might get a `std::bind()` object, and it is not prepared to store copied `std::function` objects of any size, so it has to allocate external memory in this case.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What is the underlying problem, that this information would solve? Why do you think this information would solve that problem? Please ask about the actual underlying problem directly instead (or else your question becomes an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)).

Comment: There was support for custom allocators but it was deprecated in c++17 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0302r0.html

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I want to allocate the memory with my own memory allocator. That's possible with any container, but maybe not with a function<>-object.

Comment: what do you mean with "function<>-object" ? If you write it then you are in control of how it allocates memory.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This is about the internal allocation which `std::function` requires to store the callable object, which cannot be controlled, at least since C++17.

Comment: if you mean `std::function` then you should say that ;)

Comment: Possibly avoid `std::function` entirely and go the classic C way, having a function pointer with the function accepting an additional `void*` parameter, such a `void*` pointer and leave the rest to the user? A while ago did something alike with additional wrapper around to have a convenient interface.

Comment: @Aconcagua: I need function<>-objects because they can store a whole callable object with its contents, in case of a bind()-object the parameters for it.

Comment: @BonitaMontero the parameters are stored in the `std::bind` object not in the `std::function` object. You would need `std::function` only if you want to use its type-erasure feature, as for example when storing multiple callables of different type but with the same signature into a container.

Comment: @JakobStark: That's what I wanted to say: the parameters are in the function-object (not std::function<>) being stored on the heap - and I want my own allocator.

Comment: @BonitaMontero A `std::bind` function object does not allocate memory. Only `std::function` does (depending on the wrapped callable's size).

Comment: @JakobStark: No, the object itself not, but the function<>-object takes it as a templated parameter and _copies_ it to the heap.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to determine how the external memory of a `std::function` object is allocated?

No, there isn't – at least not any more (since C++17), see comments to question.

> I need function<>-objects because they can store a whole callable object with its contents, in case of a bind()-object the parameters for it.

Well, you can *always* re-write standard templates and modify their behaviour in a manner that suits your own needs. What about a template class that copies the target (e.g. the `bind` object) and provides an `operator()` that itself calls the `bind` object? You can provide your own memory management there then:

```
class Function
{
    class WrapperBase
    {
        virtual ~WrapperBase() { }
        virtual void operator()() = 0; // with appropriate return type
                                       // and parameters – you could make
                                       // Function a template for
    };

    template <typename T>
    class Wrapper
    {
        T m_t;
    public:
        Wrapper(T& t) : m_t(t) { }
        void operator()() override
        {
            m_t();
        }
    };

public:
    template <typename T>
    Function(T& t)
    {
        void* memory = nullptr; // your personal memory allocation instead
                                // consider correct size and alignment!
        m_wrapper = new (memory) Wrapper<T>(t);
    }
    ~Function()
    {
        m_wrapper->~Wrapper(); // destructor needs to be called explicitly
        // free the memory of m_wrapper according to your personal
        // allocation strategy
    }
    
    void operator()()
    {
        (*m_wrapper)();
    }

private:
    WrapperBase* m_wrapper;
};
```

The example is incomplete, not considering const-ness of `T`, move construction etc. – you might want to add on your own.

You might want to avoid copying entirely and just store references – or specialise the templates such that objects received by normal references are stored as references only while objects received by rvalue references are copied. Endless possibilities...

Comment: How would you declare `Function::m_t`? It is used but not declared... Yet it would have a different type depending on which constructor is used.

Comment: @JakobStark Should have been `m_wrapper` whenever used... Fixed, thanks for the hint.  And I mentioned already the example not being complete.

Comment: This woudln't help since the function<>-object copyied inside the object still contains a reference to external memory. I think I've to rewrite function<> on my own.

Comment: @BonitaMontero This is what I've proposed here...

Answer (score 1):

Allocator support for `std::function` was deprecated for C++17 and not well supported by the libraries before C++17.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) for example says:

> std::function's allocator support was poorly specified and inconsistently implemented. Some implementations do not provide overloads (6-10) [these are the constructors with allocator support] at all, some provide the overloads but ignore the supplied allocator argument, and some provide the overloads and use the supplied allocator for construction but not when the std::function is reassigned. As a result, allocator support was removed in C++17.

The corresponding [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0302r0.html) with a more detailed explanation has been given in the comments to your question by @unddoch.

So I am afraid, that the answer to your question is no. There is no allocator support in `std::function`.